# ERROR: Module 'playerlib': platform 'android-28' not found

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to run my android build, I get the error - ERROR: Module 'playerlib': platform 'android-28' not found.

I went to tools -> SDK Manager to download Android 28 but I am not sure what to download exactly. Can someone provide me a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to update your SDK manager that too essential tools are: build tools platform tools tools and android Emulator.

Now go to LOGCAT, click on configure sdk and put it to latest and click auto-config button for each bar.

That should be it, rebuild it. Your Activity.xml file will be displayed with out any warning or error.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcV3W.png)

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what I need to do? I am confused

Comment: I have added an image, hopefully it clears things up. Let me know if you have any further questions.